# Converting a List to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following list where the values are appended inside a loop like:

```
appended_data.append({'A': var.FIRST, 'B':VAR.SECOND})
```

when printed:

```
appended_data[:1]
```

Output:

```
[{'A':
904 23
945   65
965   36
Name: FIRST, dtype: float64,'B': 932    54
945 66
987 45
936 90
Name: SECOND, dtype: float64}]
```

All I want to do is convert this to a pandas dataframe like so:

```
keys = ['FIRST','SECOND']
data_pol=pd.DataFrame(appended_data,columns = keys)
```

But after printing `data_pol.head()` the dataframe is empty?

Comment: Your "list" is not syntactically valid Python. What does your data actually look like?

Comment: It's been edited.

Comment: Great, now tell us how `var.FIRST` and `VAR.SECOND` are defined, and how you want them inserted into the DataFrame. Try to think ahead a little, before your question is closed as incomprehensible.

Comment: Maybe you need to show more of `appended_data` too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to call `pd.DataFrame` on the first element of `appended_data`.  You are calling it on a list.
`appended_data[:1]` is not the same as `appended_data[0]`

```
pd.DataFrame(appended_data[0])

        A     B
904  23.0   NaN
936   NaN  90.0
945  65.0  66.0
965  36.0   NaN
987   NaN  45.0
```

---

Consider the list of dictionaries of series `appended_data`

```
appended_data = [
    dict(
        A=pd.Series([23, 65, 36], [704, 745, 765]),
        B=pd.Series([66, 45, 90], [745, 787, 736])
    ),
    dict(
        A=pd.Series([23, 65, 36], [804, 845, 865]),
        B=pd.Series([66, 45, 90], [845, 887, 836])
    ),
    dict(
        A=pd.Series([23, 65, 36], [904, 945, 965]),
        B=pd.Series([66, 45, 90], [945, 987, 936])
    ),
]
```

Then we could use `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in appended_data])

        A     B
704  23.0   NaN
736   NaN  90.0
745  65.0  66.0
765  36.0   NaN
787   NaN  45.0
804  23.0   NaN
836   NaN  90.0
845  65.0  66.0
865  36.0   NaN
887   NaN  45.0
904  23.0   NaN
936   NaN  90.0
945  65.0  66.0
965  36.0   NaN
987   NaN  45.0
```

Comment: Are you sure? The OP is only showing the first element, but it seems there are a lot more.

Comment: @alexis No, I'm not sure!  I'm guessing.  Sometimes it is helpful for the OP to help formulate their ideas.  I intend to open a dialog and help identify what OP wants and expects.

Comment: Thanks.  That really helped.